# Passing values through files in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm still pretty new to C++, and I've been making progress in making my programs not look like a cluster-bleep of confusion.

I finally got rid of the various error messages, but right now the application is crashing, and I have no idea where to start.  The debugger is just throwing a random hex location.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Value{
public:
    int Val;
}*pc;

#include "header.h"

int main () {
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> pc->Val;
    cout << "\nYour value is " << pc->Val << ". ";
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pointers need to have memory allocated  pc = malloc(sizeof(Value));

Comment: @kenny: let's stay C++ here - new, not malloc. malloc would need a typecast to (Value*) anyway.

Comment: you dont need the `public` keyword inside a struct (everything is public)

Comment: I'd recommend a good book to carry you from the start.

Comment: @Seva, true pc = new Value (); didn't notice the missing .h, cin, cout....whew missed it all!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your program, pc is not a struct - it's a pointer to the struct (because of *). You don't initialize it to anything - it points at some bogus location. So, either initialize it in the first line of main():

```
pc = new Value();
```

Or make it a non-pointer by removing *, and use . instead of -> for member access throughout the program.

Answer (score 3):

`pc` is a pointer but you haven't given it valid memory to point to.  You have a couple of choices.

You can use an object instead of a pointer and use it like an object:

```
struct Value{
public:
    int Val;
} c;

    ...
    cin >> c.Val;
    cout << c.Val;
```

You can keep as a pointer and have it point to something valid.  Easiest way is to `new` an object and remember to `delete` it later:

```
int main()
{
    pc = new Value;

    ...

    delete pc;
}
```

Comment: i know a joke.. 'airplane gets lost, and flies around some high building. there's opened window, with some working man inside, and the pilot asks 'where am I?'. that man replies 'in a plane'.. pilot says 'you must be an IT, aren't you?' 'why?' 'you gave me perfectly correct answer, but totally useless.''

Comment: That joke has a continuation, you know. "And you must be a manager." "Why?" "You don't know where you are and where you're going, you ask me for help, I give you a perfectly correct answer, now you still don't know where you are and where you're going, but now it's my fault somehow."

Comment: That joke finally lost its flavour!

Answer (score 3):

You never initialized 'pc'. It's an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `pc` is a `pointer` to the struct `Value`

Why don't you assign it first after the `int main()` declaration, like

```
pc = new Value();
```

By compiler default `pc = NULL;`. PS. In C++, you have to manage your own Garbage collection, so once you're done, do this:

```
delete pc; //It frees memory....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The value of uninitialized variables is officially an undefined behavior in C++. Depending on compiler, could be NULL or anything.

Comment: Yes, correct! @Seva. What I meant to say is that the compiler creates a word register (address space) for `pc` which contains a non-existant address. It bombs out signally a `segmentation fault` and terminates.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Value{
public:
    int Val;
}*pc;



int main () {


    pc = new Value();

    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> pc->Val;
    cout << "\nYour value is " << pc->Val << ". ";

    delete pc;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although it doesn't matter in practice because this is in `main()`, you should put a `delete pc` before your `return` statement to avoid leaking memory.